# Data is incomplete en una llamada API desde android

Tags: php, java, android, api, rest

Tengo una API que recibe dos parámetros mediante POST, pero cuando uno de ellos es "0" no realiza la llamada a la base de datos para la inserción del valor. Cualquier otro valor SI funciona.

Esta es la llamada desde Android:

```
public void registerResult(TestFinalizado test, String usuario) {
    Log.d("RESPONSE", "entrandoooo");

    OkHttpClient okhttpclient = new OkHttpClient();
    String url_insert = "http://larutademiapi.com/API/objeto/insert.php";

    RequestBody data = new FormBody.Builder()
            .add("username",usuario)
            .add("resultado",""+test.getResultado())
            .build();

    Log.d("RESPONSE", data.toString());

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(url_insert)
            .post(data)
            .build();

    Log.d("RESPONSE", request.body().toString());

    okhttpclient.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
            Log.d("RESPONSE", response.body().string());
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                TestFinalizadoFactory.this.finishedApiAccess = 1;   //         <------ INDICAMOS QUE HEMOS TERMINADO CON LA LLAMADA A LA API.
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Mi clase del objeto dentro de la API:
La fecha Id es AUTO_INCREMENT y la fecha se calcula mediante php con la fecha actual, no se le pasan como parámetros. Los 2 únicos parámetros son Username y Resultado.

```
<?php
class TestFinalizado{

    // database connection and table name
    private $conn;
    private $table_name = "TestFinalizado";

    // object properties
    public $Id;
    public $Username;
    public $Resultado;
    public $Fecha;

    // constructor with $db as database connection
    public function __construct($db){
        $this->conn = $db;
    }


    /* ---------- OTRAS FUNCIONES ---------- */

    public function insert(){

        // query to insert record
        $query = "INSERT INTO " . $this->table_name . " SET Username=:Username, Resultado=:Resultado, Fecha=:Fecha";

        // prepare query
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);

        // sanitize
        $this->Username=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->Username));
        $this->Resultado=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->Resultado));
        $this->Fecha=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->Fecha));

        // bind values
        $stmt->bindParam(":Username", $this->Username);
        $stmt->bindParam(":Resultado", $this->Resultado);
        $stmt->bindParam(":Fecha", $this->Fecha);

        // execute query
        if($stmt->execute()){
            return true;
        }

        return false;

    }
}
?>
```

Y por último el archivo insert.php

```
<?php
// required headers
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST");
header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");

// get database connection
include_once '../config/database.php';

// instantiate testfinalizado object
include_once '../objects/testfinalizado.php';

$database = new Database();
$db = $database->getConnection();

$testfinalizado = new TestFinalizado($db);

$data;

// get data
$data->Username = isset($_POST['username']) ? $_POST['username'] : die();
$data->Resultado = isset($_POST['resultado']) ? $_POST['resultado'] : die();
$data->Fecha = date("Y-m-d");


// make sure data is not empty
if(
    !empty($data->Username) &&
    !empty($data->Resultado) &&
    !empty($data->Fecha)
){

    // set testfinalizado property values
    $testfinalizado->Username = $data->Username;
    $testfinalizado->Resultado = $data->Resultado;
    $testfinalizado->Fecha = $data->Fecha;

    // create the testfinalizado
    if($testfinalizado->insert()){

        // set response code - 201 created
        http_response_code(201);

        // tell the user
        echo json_encode(array("message" => "testfinalizado was created."));
    }

    // if unable to create the testfinalizado, tell the user
    else{

        // set response code - 503 service unavailable
        http_response_code(503);

        // tell the user
        echo json_encode(array("message" => "Unable to create testfinalizado."));
    }
}

// tell the user data is incomplete
else{

    print_r($data);

    // set response code - 400 bad request
    http_response_code(400);

    // tell the user
    echo json_encode(array("message" => "Unable to create testfinalizado. Data is incomplete."));
}
?>
```

Lo que no se es por qué cuando se le pasa como parámetro un 0 en resultado, no está entrando en este if:

```
// make sure data is not empty
if(
    !empty($data->Username) &&
    !empty($data->Resultado) &&
    !empty($data->Fecha)
){
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creo que el detalle se encuentra en la linea `!empty($data->Resultado)` de tu `if`. Cuándo le pasas un cero a la función `empty()` de php devuelve un verdadero ya que el cero es considerado un valor vacío.
Quizá deberias utilizar otra función para validar, como un `count()` o `isset()`

Puedes ver ejemplos de como funciona `empty()` [aquí](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.empty.php)

Comment: Exacto!! Eso era. Muchas gracias.